# Unsupported engine while issueing an npm install command in the angular project root

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I am having an angular project. I am using a macbook .

when i issue an npm install it is giving the following error.

appreciate if you can provide some clues

```
Prasanths-MacBook-Air:primecast-web kannan$ npm install
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'express-csv@0.6.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '0.6 || 0.8 || 0.10' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.0.0', npm: '7.10.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/kannan/openmindcvs/primecast-web/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.0.0 | darwin | x64
npm ERR! (node:14186) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/kannan/openmindcvs/primecast-web/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/kannan/openmindcvs/primecast-web/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/kannan/openmindcvs/primecast-web/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/kannan/.node-gyp/16.0.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/kannan/.node-gyp/16.0.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/kannan/openmindcvs/primecast-web/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/kannan/.node-gyp/16.0.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/kannan/openmindcvs/primecast-web/node_modules/node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/kannan/openmindcvs/primecast-web/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:365:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/16.0.0_1/bin/node" "/Users/kannan/openmindcvs/primecast-web/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/kannan/openmindcvs/primecast-web/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
```

my node version is v16.0.0

```
   Prasanths-MacBook-Air:primecast-web kannan$ node -v
    v16.0.0
```

my angular cli version is 12.2.5

```
Prasanths-MacBook-Air:primecast-web kannan$ ng --version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 12.2.5
Node: 16.0.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 7.10.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: <error>
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1202.5 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         12.2.5 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   12.2.5 (cli-only)
@angular/cli                 12.2.5 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          12.2.5 (cli-only)
rxjs                         6.6.7 (cli-only)
typescript                   <error>
    
Warning: The current version of Node (16.0.0) is not supported by Angular
```

I am using a macbook. appreciate if you can give a clue on how to fix the issue

thank you